# c# write 1-25 to listbox; concise way to do this?

Tags: c#

C# is program.

I am writing a program which requires a list box with numbers 1-25 as entries. I am certain there is a more concise way to do this.

How can I concise this code?

Here is current code:

```
shiftListBox.Text = "";
shiftListBox.Items.Add("Random");
shiftListBox.Items.Add("1"); //is there a more concise way to write this- with a loop, for example?
shiftListBox.Items.Add("2");
shiftListBox.Items.Add("3");
shiftListBox.Items.Add("4");
shiftListBox.Items.Add("5");
shiftListBox.Items.Add("6");
shiftListBox.Items.Add("7");
shiftListBox.Items.Add("8");
shiftListBox.Items.Add("9");
shiftListBox.Items.Add("10");
shiftListBox.Items.Add("11");
shiftListBox.Items.Add("12");
shiftListBox.Items.Add("13");
shiftListBox.Items.Add("14");
shiftListBox.Items.Add("15");
shiftListBox.Items.Add("16");
shiftListBox.Items.Add("17");
shiftListBox.Items.Add("18");
shiftListBox.Items.Add("19");
shiftListBox.Items.Add("20");
shiftListBox.Items.Add("21");
shiftListBox.Items.Add("22");
shiftListBox.Items.Add("23");
shiftListBox.Items.Add("24");
shiftListBox.Items.Add("25");
```

Comment: Aren't you glad that you didn't have to write 1-100000? In general, if you find yourself repeating something like this you're most likely doing something wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Use iteration. Or LINQ. Here's a LINQ sample.

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 25).ToList().ForEach(x => shiftListBox.Items.Add(x));
```

Don't forget to import the LINQ namespace at the top of your code.

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: I would write the same way. Instead of ForEach().Items.Add() part, I would simply make it the DataSource of shiftListBox.

Comment: `Enumerable.Range` is so useful :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a for loop:

```
shiftListBox.Items.Add("Random");

for (int i = 1; i < 26; i++)
{
    shiftListBox.Items.Add(i);
}
```